# Foreign Key in NDB/Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am building a web app with Google Endpoints and the Datastore using NDB in Google App Engine. Each user that signs in has a set of "watched listings" that is just a repeated property in the expando model of NDB like this:

**class user(ndb.Expando):**

```
username = ndb.StringProperty()
email = ndb.StringProperty()
password = ndb.StringProperty()
overallRanking = ndb.IntegerProperty()
numRankings = ndb.IntegerProperty()
watchedListings = ndb.KeyProperty(modelListing,repeated=True)
```

As you can see, I am storing the key of modelListing entities. However, when I delete a modelListing, I want it to automatically delete the key for all of the users that have that key in their watchedListings object. This is similar to how SQL would handle a foreign key. Is there a way to do this without going through all the users in the database and searching for that key, deleting it, and executing a put()?

Answer (score 0):

I did to try this feature yet. It looks like you can do the job using:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities?hl=nl#hooks